# Optional AnyObject values in Swift dictionary

Tags: swift, swift3, option-type, anyobject, swift-dictionary

When I add a value of type 'AnyObject?' to a dictionary of Type '[String : AnyObject]' in the following way, the value can not by added, which is actually what I've expected. Assigning an optional type to a non-optional type should fail in my opinion.

```
var myDict : [String : AnyObject] = [ "Key1" : "Value1" as AnyObject? ]
```

But why does this procedure work if I first initialize an empty dictionary and then add the value to it?

```
var myDict = [String : AnyObject]()
myDict["Key1"] = "Value1" as AnyObject?
```

I've seen this approach in the GenericKeychain example from Apple
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: What's the used version of Swift? the second code snippet is also giving me a compile-time error

Comment: @AhmadF second code snippet works fine for me, Swift 3, Xcode 8.2

Comment: @JAL I see, currently, I am on a machine that uses xcode 7/Swift 2 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second line works because the `subscript` override for Dictionary uses an Optional:

```
subscript(key: Key) -> Value? { get set }
```

Whereas the initializer for a Dictionary of type `[String : AnyObject]` requires concrete types:

[image: Dictionary init]

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you're using a dictionary literal. The values in a dictionary literal must match the dictionary's `Value` type.

In the second example, you're using `Dictionary`'s `subscript(key: Key) -> Value?` subscript to assign a value. Here, `Value?` can be optional, which you can use to remove a key/value pair by assigning `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

In the above example, `myDict` is inferred with non-optional `AnyObject` while the assigned is optional `AnyObject`. That is the reason for the error. This will resolve your issue.

```
var myDict : [String : AnyObject?] = [ "Key1" : "Value1" as AnyObject?]
```

Comment: Yes, but this answer does not explain *why* the subscript can take an optional, but the dictionary literal cannot.